# In C, how do I write to file from a MacOSX app bundle

Tags: c, macos, file-io, core-foundation

I want to debug some stuff in my application by dumping text to a file, like this:

```
FILE *file; 
file = fopen("/tmp/file.txt","a+");
fprintf(file,"%s\n", "silly debug message"); 
fclose(file);
```

That works when I run the file as ./myapplication.  But when I bundle it as an app bundle (using [gtk-osx-application](https://live.gnome.org/GTK+/OSX/Integration) and [gtk-mac-bundler](https://github.com/jralls/gtk-mac-bundler)) and run the app bundle, the file isn't created.  It fails silently and continues execution.

Any ideas why?  Is there some sandboxing going on?

Comment: Is sandboxing involved?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I don't really know, I ask the same question in the last paragraph :)

Comment: It looks like there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this isn't a real question anymore.  The problem was that I had an extra MyApp.app in the root folder / in addition to the app I thought I was testing in /Application.  When using "open -a MyApp", the old app version in the root folder was used.

That's a couple of hours of my life that I'll never get back.  Oh well.  Thanks for you feedback, people.  I know more about NSLog(), CFShow(), CFString and syslog() now, and that's extremely helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your app bundle is sandboxed so you can't write to arbitrary locations in the file system (like `/tmp`). To access a temp directory specific to your app, instead use [NSTemporaryDirectory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSTemporaryDirectory);

```
import <NSPathUtilities.h>

NSString* tempPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
```

See some more info on file system access [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW15).

Comment: His program is C, so doesn't have access to `NSString`.  I'm not sure how he can get it to work without adding some Objective-C to his app.

Comment: @trojanfoe Bad reading comprehension on my part, missed the `C` tag. I'm not aware of any way of doing this without mixing in ObjectiveC, although it should be possible to isolate the required Foundation calls to a single, system dependent, file.

Comment: I have access to CFString, though: "This is especially true since CFString is toll-free bridged with NSString, enabling
any NSString instance to be used as a CFString."  (from CFString.h).  I haven't found an equivalent for the NSTemporaryDirectory() yet.

Answer (score 1):

When I create a test app, with sandboxing, and add additional error checking:

```
FILE *file = fopen("/tmp/file.txt","a+");
if (file != NULL)
{
    fprintf(file,"%s\n", "silly debug message");
    fclose(file);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to create file: %d", errno);
}
```

I get:

```
2013-02-09 10:19:43.680 WriteTest[11988:303] Failed to create file: 1
```

From the command line:

```
$ perror 1 
1       : Operation not permitted
```

So you aren't permitted to write to `/tmp` in an app sandbox.  You need to follow the [App Sandbox Design Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) to determine where you can write files, perhaps using Core Foundation and functions like `CFCopyHomeDirectoryURL()` to get the location of files you can write to within a sandboxed environment.

Comment: Somehow NSLog fails to write anything anywhere, as far as I can see.  It fails silently as well.  To which file is it supposed to log?

Comment: @neu242 NSLog output should afaik be visible in the console app, I've not tested on an app bundled app though.

Comment: I thought so as well, but there's nothing from my app there.

Comment: I viewed that output from the debugger pane of Xcode. It goes to stdout, so you can probably see it by starting the app with `$ open /Applications/MyApp.app`.

Comment: By sending a CFString to CFShow(), I got my message to stdout, but only when running as ./myapplication.  "open" spawns a new process, so I'm not seeing anything in the Terminal.  And still nothing is visible from Console. :(